# Создать плавную анимацию поворота текста wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf

есть текст, который должен плавно повернуться при нажатии на него. Можно сделать чтобы он повернулся на 1 градус, подождал 50мс, повернулся на 1 градус и так до полного поворота. Но мне кажется это неправильно, ведь во время этого поворота лаунчер "зависнет", даже если делать анимацию в другом потоке. Потому что изменять элементы на форме можно только через главный поток, и обращаться к нему надо с помощью Dispatcher. Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно сделать анимацию по кругу.

Comment: С помощью средств встроенной в WPF анимации

Comment: Попробуйте поковырять вот это https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/16.php

Comment: Во первых, какой смысл давать вам ответы, если вы их не принимаете? Во вторых, вы покажите наверно то, что вы пытаетесь сделать, ваши попытки.